# C++11 nested macro invocation?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, macros

It says in C++ std 16.3.4:

> The resulting preprocessing token sequence [from a macro invocation replacement]
>   is rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to
>   replace.
>
> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the
>   rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced.
>
> Furthermore, if **any nested replacements** encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced.
>
> These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacement even if they are later (re)examined in contexts
>   in which that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.

**What exactly is a nested macro replacement?**

Specifically consider:

```
#define f(x) 1 x
#define g(x) 2 x

g(f)(g)(3)
```

I would have expected the following:

```
g(f)(g)(3)    <-- first replacement of g, ok
2 f(g)(3)     <-- nested replacement of f, ok
2 1 g(3)      <-- second nested replacement of g, don't replace, stop
```

However gcc unexpectedly goes ahead with the second replacement of g, producing:

```
2 1 2 3
```

Any ideas?

**Update:**

After much research, let me clear up this issue with a simpler example:

```
#define A(x) B
#define B(x) A(x)

A(i)(j)
```

This expands as follows:

```
A(i)(j)
B(j)
A(j)
```

The standard does not specify whether `A(j)` should be expanded to `B` or not.  The committee decided to leave it this way because real world programs are not expected to depend on this behavior, so both leaving `A(j)` unexpanded and expanding `A(j)` to `B` are considered conformant.

Comment: For reference, if you do something like this: http://ideone.com/6OVgPB you do see the behavior that it talks about (I think). I have no idea what the difference is.

Comment: I believe this behaviour is only to prevent infinite loops. Because your example can't produce an infinite loop, it's fine to expand fully. My *guess* is that the exact distinction is that `g(3)` only became a full token by combining the result of `f` with surrounding content, whereas if you had `#define g(x) f(x) #define f(x) g(x)`, the `g(x)` would be defined entirely within `f(x)`, so would stop (and therefore avoid an infinite loop)

Comment: compilers vary wildly in their exact rules for preprocessor, not particularly standard conforming. the boost preprocessor library abstracts those differences away for many common cases, by way of compiler detection. it may be the closest thing to a *real* standard

Comment: @Dave: If that were so than you would expect `#define f(x) f(` to preprocess an input of `f(a)a)a)a)` to an output of `f(`, correct?  However gcc terminates at first call and returns `f(a)a)a)`

Comment: @user1131467 yes, I would. There must be something more subtle going on, but I can't see any logical pattern.

Comment: My experience says C preprocessor treat a #define with arguments different than a #define with none.  And also a #define name followed by a '(' differently than one without.

Comment: @brianbeuning: Yes, one is called an object-like macro, the other is called a function-like macro.  An invocation of a function-like macro starts if and only if the macro name is followed by an opening `(`.  My question is when are two macro invocations considered nested with respect to each other.

Comment: @user1131467 You are asking for an interpretation of the standard.  I don't have that answer.  The C pre-processors I use seem to just check recursion level and give an error after a certain depth.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in the preprocessor of GCC, some other implementations do produce `2 1 g (3)`.

Comment: This seems like a cross post from: http://forum.cppgm.org/question/915/course-defined-macro-expansion-rule/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This explains the original intent, and why no clarifications have been added to the standard about this subject:

http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#268

---

> ### 268. Macro name suppression in rescanned replacement text
>
> **Section**: 16.3.4  [cpp.rescan]     **Status**: open     **Submitter**: Bjarne Stroustrup     **Date**: 18 Jan 2001
>
> It is not clear from the Standard what the result of the following example should be:
>
> ```
> #define NIL(xxx) xxx
> #define G_0(arg) NIL(G_1)(arg)
> #define G_1(arg) NIL(arg)
> G_0(42)
> ```
>
> The relevant text from the Standard is found in 16.3.4 [cpp.rescan] paragraph 2:
>
> > [snipped]
>
> The sequence of expansion of `G0(42)` is as follows:
>
> ```
> G0(42)
> NIL(G_1)(42)
> G_1(42)
> NIL(42)
> ```
>
> The question is whether the use of `NIL` in the last line of this sequence qualifies for non-replacement under the cited text. If it does, the result will be `NIL(42)`. If it does not, the result will be simply `42`.
>
> **The original intent of the J11 committee in this text was that the result should be `42`, as demonstrated by the original pseudo-code description of the replacement algorithm provided by Dave Prosser, its author.** The English description, however, omits some of the subtleties of the pseudo-code and thus arguably gives an incorrect answer for this case.
>
> *Suggested resolution (Mike Miller)*: [snipped]
>
> #### Notes (via Tom Plum) from April, 2004 WG14 Meeting:
>
> Back in the 1980's it was understood by several WG14 people that there were tiny differences between the "non-replacement" verbiage and the attempts to produce pseudo-code. **The committee's decision was that no realistic programs "in the wild" would venture into this area, and trying to reduce the uncertainties is not worth the risk of changing conformance status of implementations or programs.**

Comment: In the DR's example, there is a 4-step sequence of expansion for `G_0` which goes twice through `NIL`. That is the issue at hand there. In this question, each expansion is only one step and occurs in response to additional tokens read from the source file. The Standard specifies that subsequent tokens aren't subject to non-replacement, so the DR doesn't apply.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: No, that is incorrect.  The issue is whether the first `NIL` is nested with respect to the second (`NIL->G_1->NIL`).  It would still be the same issue if the original input were `NIL(G_1)(42)` instead of `G0(42)`.  It is the same issue as the OP (`f->g->f`).  As `NIL(G_1)` produces just the head token of `G_1` and does not include the trailing `(42)`, the issue is whether `G_1` is nested within the previous `NIL`.  The standard intentionally leaves this unspecified, so either interpretation is correct.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: And when you are thinking about this, compare it to the expansion of `NIL(NIL)(42)`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I added an update to the OP with a simpler example that highlights the issue and explains the conclusion.

Comment: I wonder why the committee decided to leave the standard language alone and didn't "standardize" the behavior in question as 'unspecified'? That would seem to more accurately reflect the committee's intent based on the 2004 comment.

Answer (score 0):

`g(x)` is always replaced by `2 x`. In the second nested replacement of g, you call `g(x)` with `x=3`, so this produces the result `2 3`. My understanding is that the compiler doesn't replace the macro with it's value, in case this produces an infinite loop:

```
#define g( x ) f( x )
#define f( x ) g( x )

g( 1 ) -- > f( 1 ) --> stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it mentions "(not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens)." The first replacement of `g` only sees `f`. Now `f` is eligible for replacement with the preprocessing tokens taken from the rest of the file, but nowhere does the program record that `f` was produced by `g`. The replacement of `f(g)` produces a `g` which is likewise untainted by recursion.

A nested replacement is one that is enclosed by another replacement, not one whose tokens were sourced from another replacement. By the latter definition, a replacement could have several mutually exclusive nesting parents.

Comment: It's not that simple unfortunately.  It depends if you think a macro invocation is "enclosed" by another if its macro name is part of the replaced tokens, or the entire invocation (including closing paren) is part of the replaced tokens.  Further should the one degree case (f->f) be different from the multiple degree nested case (f->g->f).  As stated in the other answer, the standard intentionally leaves this unspecified as no real programs are expected to depend on the difference - so there are multiple conformant interpretations.

Comment: @user1131467 Any reasonable definition of nesting allows only one parent. The invocation is the entire invocation, and the macro name isn't a special part of it vis a vis replacement. In any case, the paragraph isn't talking about syntax, it's the *process* of replacement where they are nested. Tokens can take convoluted paths through the program before becoming part of an invocation and undergoing replacement. Even if the standard is ambiguous, that DR says that my reading corresponds to the intent. Anyway, I dare you to find an otherwise-conforming implementation different from the rest.

Comment: I don't think you understand what is going on.  `#define f(x) g(x)` and `#define g(x) f(x)`, then expand the text `f(1)`: `f(1)` is replaced with `g(1)`, then it is rescanned, `g(1)` is replaced with `f(1)`, and then it is rescanned, `f(1)` is _not_ replaced again as `f` is a nested "two degree" "two parent" non-replaced token from the original invocation of f (f->g->f).  This case is uncontroversial and what all implementations do.  The special case is only when a rescanned invocation crosses the boundary between the previously replaced invocation and the rest of the file.

Comment: As for finding a preprocessor implementation different from the rest, this is very easy, take a look at the Boost.Preprocessor library config file, and you will soon see how standardized preprocessor behaviour is.  There are about eight different flavors each with its own quirks.  I'm told there are ones that not only vary on this particular issue - but on many other behaviours as well.

Comment: That doesn't mean any quirks mode is conformant. I understand well; I wrote my own conformant implementation. And your last description is unrelated to the issue at hand. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your "one parent" statement.  My point is that there are several different implementations that are conformant, and one cannot be judged objectively more "reasonable" than another.  Specifically outputting _either_ `2 1 2 3` or `2 1 g(3)` for the OP program is considered conformant, and there are production preprocessors for both behaviours.  The original intent of the feature is to avoid infinite loops at compile-time, and there are several architectures to achieve this.

Comment: @user1131467 Actually, no. Your program is different from the DR program and even if that one is ambiguous (I think it's not), yours isn't. There is no way for `g` to be found "during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens)", because the second `g` token is one of "the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens". QED. In the DR, though, the `NIL` participates in two rescanning-replacement steps of the same list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30449/discussion-between-potatoswatter-and-user1131467)

Comment: I've researched this issue quite thoroughally last month and I can assure you that you are wrong. The f token is part of the first g invocations replaced tokens. The g token is part of the f invocations replaced tokens. Therefore g is nested with respect to itself (`g`->`f`->`g`) and becomes non-replaced. This is one conformant interpretation, to consider the relationship based on the macro head token as it is done in the first degree case.  This is the same issue as in the proposed change (`NIL`->`G_1`->`NIL`).

Comment: @user1131467 Please click the chat link.

Comment: Regarding your final example in chat, it doesn't seem relevant at all.  Under all conformant interpretations the result is XY.

Comment: @user1131467 I gave an example of pasting two replacement lists because that is what you asked for. No more, no less.

Comment: Well clearly I would expect a case involving concatenation that results in different behavior between the two different interpretations.  Frankly I don't see how concatenation is relevant.