# How to Interpret This Paragraph of the C++ Standard Related to Macro Replacement

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

There is a paragraph in the C++03 standard related to preprocessor macro replacement:

> 16.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement
>
> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of
>   the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s
>   preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. **Further, if any *nested
>   replacements* encounter the *name of the macro being replaced*, it is not
>   replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no
>   longer available for further replacement even if they are later
>   (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token
>   would otherwise have been replaced.**

What do the highlighted sentences mean?  First the standard never defined the term "*nested replacements*". Furthermore, if a nested replacement means the example given below

```
#define a b
#define b c
#define c d
#define d a b e
#define e m

a // expanded to "a b m"
```

Which one is the *"name of the macro being replaced*"(note singular noun used) ? Because here `a` is replaced to `b` then to `c` then to `d` then to `a b m`, and there are >1 macros being replaced and both `a` & `b` are the name of the macros encountered previously. But clearly the standard is not using a plural noun so it should not mean both `a` and `b` here.

Can someone clarify the meaning of this paragraph.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583021/c11-nested-macro-invocation

Comment: The standard considers each macro being replaced separately, hence grammatical singular. This does not mean more than one such macro cannot exist at the same time.

Comment: The rule is applied twice. Since `a` is being replaced, it's not replaced when it's encountered in `d`. In the same way, since `b` is also being replaced, it's not replaced when it's encountered in `d`, either. There's no need for a plural.

Comment: There is kind of Matryoshka doll of replacements. As you say, `a` is replaced by `b`, then `b` is replaced by `c` etc; but that is not done sequentially - the replacements are nested into one another. The inner replacements are regarded as part of the outer one. Therefore, the replacement of macro `d` is nested with respect to the replacement of macro `a`.